# Where is sched_clock for arm64

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, clock, arm64

I am trying to find the sched_clock defination for arm64 but could not find it, where and how it is implemented .

For example for x86, following is where it is defined

```
 #ifdef CONFIG_PARAVIRT
 unsigned long long sched_clock(void)
 {
     return paravirt_sched_clock();
 }
 #else
 unsigned long long
 sched_clock(void) __attribute__((alias("native_sched_clock")));
 #endif
```

Same way it is defined for other archtectitures.

Could any one point me out for arm64 how it is implemented?

Comment: Probably, arm64 uses generic `sched_clock` implementation, [this one](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/clock.c#L70), or [that one](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/sched_clock.c#L96), if `CONFIG_GENERIC_SCHED_CLOCK` is set.

Comment: Thank you, it looks to me the latter one but how if CONFIG_GENERIC_SCHED_CLOCK  is set unsigned long long notrace sched_clock() will be called?

Comment: I am not sure, probably because of `__weak` attribute in the other case means "link to this function only if no other choice".